# Display content of document from Document library in custom webpart

Tags: web-part, document-library, document

I have a site in sharepoint.I have a one Document library in site. I like to load the content of particular document in my custom web part.

how do I get content of particular document using code behind? I like to display particular document content in my literal control in my custom web part.

Comment: if it's SharePoint 2013, use Office Web Apps server otherwise your question is duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41268/document-preview-in-sharepoint-2010 :)

Comment: No...I want to display Document contents in my web part not to be display on hover.....for now think about that there is only one document in document library and that I want to display